# parsing huge csv file into mysql [python]

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I have some problems with parsing huge csv file into mysql databse.

Csv file looks like this:

```
ref1  data1  data2  data3...
ref1  data4  data5  data6...
ref2  data1  data2  data3 data4 data5..
ref2  data12 data13 data14
ref2  data21 data22...
.
.
.
```

Csv file has about 1 milion lines or about 7MB in zip file or about 150MB unzip.

My job is to parse the data from csv into mysql, but only the data/lines when references matches. Another problem is, that from multiple lines in csv i must parse it in only one line in mysql for one reference.

I tryed to do this with csv.reader and for loops on each references, but is ultra slow.

```
with con:
cur.execute("SELECT ref FROM users")
user=cur.fetchall()
for i in range(len(user)):
    with open('hugecsv.csv', mode='rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')                               
        for row in reader:
            if(str(user[i][0])==row[0]):
                writer.writerow(row)
```

So i have all references which i would like to parse, in my list user. Which is the fastes way to parse?

Please help!

Comment: Please clarify "from multiple lines in csv i must parse it in only one line".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first obvious bottleneck is that you are reopening and scanning the whole CSV file for each user in your database. Doing a single pass on the csv would be faster :

```
# faster lookup on users
cur.execute ("select ref from users")
users = set(row[0] for row in cur.fetchall())

with open("your/file.CSV") as f:
    r = reader(f)
    for row in r:
        if row[0] in users:
            do_something_with(row)
```

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, what exactly set() do? Becuse python does not return any errors but variable users does't exsist when i run code

Comment: `set` is a builtin type, it's a collection of unique elements with fast (0(1)) lookup. But there was an error in my code (sorry answered from my phone), which I just fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'EF_PerechenSkollekciyami.csv' TO `TABLE_NAME` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
```

This is an internal query command in mysql.

I don't recommend you to use tabs to separate columns, and recommend you to change this by sed to ; or something another character. But you can try with tabs too.

Comment: Why don't you recommend tab separated columns? MySQL uses this my default. And why terminate with `;`?

Comment: I get csv file every month from multiple companyes and i would like to use python to parse, becuse i need control on parsing (time stamp that program is running automaticly, log files with errors, another py programs to control resources...)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included all your logic. If you just want to import everything into a single table,

```
cur.execute("LOAD DATA INFILE 'path_to_file.csv' INTO TABLE my_table;")
```

MySQL does it directly. You can't get any faster than that.

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Comment: basicly i must filter my csv file and write into mysql just lines on which reference matches.

Comment: What about importing the CSV, and then running a SQL query to do the filtering?

Comment: This is option but i don't know how to do this becuse i have very dinamicly csv file. For example i don't know how many lines i have for one user/reference.

Comment: @djpiky you can load your file into temporary table with no indexes and then extract only the relevant records into the actual table.